# Moving an email to a different folder with a watcher

Tags: vba, email, outlook

In a particular folder within an inbox I to extract the attachment and save the body of the email as a text file.

I attach those two onto an email to send to a different mailbox (Mailbox2) which has a file-watcher.

How do I move the email to a different folder once received in Mailbox2?

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set NS = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Inbox As Folder
Set Inbox = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim SubFolder As Folder
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("TESTER")

Dim Destination As String
Destination = "MyFolder\"

Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim txtFile As String

For Each Email In SubFolder.Items
    For Each Atmt In Email.Attachments
        If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
            FileName = Destination & Email.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next Atmt

    Subject = Email.SenderName
    
    Dim rmv As Variant
    rmv = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")
    
    Dim r As Variant 
    
    For Each r In rmv 
        Subject = Replace(Subject, r, "")
    Next r
    
    txtFile = Destination & Subject & ".txt"
    
    Open txtFile For Output As #1
        Write #1, Email.Body
    Close #1
    
    Call Send_Mail(Subject)
    Call DeleteExample
Next Email

End Sub


Public Sub Send_Mail(Subject As String)
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    StrPath = "MyFolder\"
  
    With OutlookMail
        .Display
        .To = "Mailbox2@gmail.com"
        .CC = "Mailbox2@gmail.com"
        .BCC = "Mailbox2@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Test mail"
        strfile = Dir(StrPath & "*.*")
        Do While Len(strfile) > 0
            If (Right(strfile, 3) = "txt" Or Right(strfile, 3) = "pdf" Or Right(strfile, 4) = "xlsx") Then
                .Attachments.Add StrPath & strfile
            End If
        strfile = Dir
    Loop
    .Send
  End With
End Sub


Sub DeleteExample()
'Deletes all files in the folder
    Kill "MyFolder\*.*"
End Sub
```

I have been attempting to embed this logic within the for loop in `Application_NewMail()`.

```vb
For Each Email In SubFolder.Items
    For Each Atmt In Email.Attachments
        If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
            FileName = Destination & Email.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next Atmt

    Subject = Email.SenderName
    
    Dim rmv As Variant
    rmv = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")
    
    Dim r As Variant 
    
    For Each r In rmv 
        Subject = Replace(Subject, r, "")
    Next r
    
    txtFile = Destination & Subject & ".txt"
    
    Open txtFile For Output As #1
        Write #1, Email.Body
    Close #1
    
    Call Send_Mail(Subject)
    Call DeleteExample
    Call MoveEmail()

Next Email
```

```
Sub MoveEmail()
Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set NS = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Inbox As Folder
Set Inbox = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim SubFolder As Folder
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("TESTER")

For Each Email In SubFolder.Items
    SubFolder.MoveTo (Inbox.Folders("END"))
Next Email

End Sub
```

Yet it is moving the entire "TESTER" folder into the "END" folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Messing with it some more I found out how to move the email to a different folder.

Here is the logic

```
Sub MoveEmail()
Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set NS = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Inbox As Folder
Set Inbox = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim SubFolder As Folder
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("TESTER")

   For Each Email In SubFolder.Items
      Email.Move (Inbox.Folders("END"))
   Next Email


End Sub
```

Comment: [Why do I have to run For Each code several times to move emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77350815/why-do-i-have-to-run-for-each-code-several-times-to-move-emails)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "for each" when modifying a collection - use a down loop:

```
set items = SubFolder.Items
for i = items.Count to 1 step -1
  set Email = items(i)
  Email.Move (Inbox.Folders("END"))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

`NewMailEx` may be a better choice than `NewMail`.

Process each item when received.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()
    Dim eID As String
    'eID = ActiveInspector.currentItem.EntryID
    eID = ActiveExplorer.selection(1).EntryID
    Debug.Print eID
    Application_NewMailEx eID
End Sub

Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex
' EntryIDCollection is no longer a collection, has only one ID.

' In ThisOutlookSession

Dim objItem As Object
Dim email As mailItem

Set objItem = Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
Debug.Print "NewMailEx: " & objItem.Subject

Dim Destination As String
Destination = "MyFolder\"

Dim Atmt As Attachment

Dim FileName As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim txtFile As String

If objItem.Class = olMail Then

    Set email = objItem
    
    For Each Atmt In email.Attachments
        'If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
            FileName = Destination & email.senderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
            Debug.Print FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
        'End If
    Next Atmt

    Subject = email.senderName
    
    Dim rmv As Variant
    rmv = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")
    
    Dim r As Variant
    
    For Each r In rmv
        Subject = Replace(Subject, r, "")
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print Subject
    
    txtFile = Destination & Subject & ".txt"
    Debug.Print txtFile
    
    Open txtFile For Output As #1
        Write #1, email.Body
    Close #1
    
    Call Send_Mail(Subject)
    Call DeleteExample
    
    Dim Inbox As Folder
    Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    email.Move Inbox.Folders("END")
    
End If

End Sub


Public Sub Send_Mail(Subject As String)

    Dim outlookMail As mailItem
    Set outlookMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    strPath = "MyFolder\"
    strFile = cFldrPathUserTest

    With outlookMail
        .Display
        .To = "Mailbox2@gmail.com"
        .CC = "Mailbox2@gmail.com"
        .BCC = "Mailbox2@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Test mail"
        strFile = dir(strPath & "*.*")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            If (Right(strFile, 3) = "txt" Or Right(strFile, 3) = "pdf" Or Right(strFile, 4) = "xlsx") Then
                .Attachments.Add strPath & strFile
            End If
        strFile = dir
    Loop
    '.Send
  End With
  
End Sub


Sub DeleteExample()
'Deletes all files in the folder
'    Kill "MyFolder\*.*"
End Sub
```