# Why do I have to run For Each code several times to move emails?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have to run this code several times to move emails to the archive folder. The script will first move Emails whose body contains "now rows selected". In the 2nd and 3rd run, it will move emails whose body contains "Es wurden keine Zeilen ausgewählt".

```vb
Sub Search_Move_Email()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim sText As String
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim mySearchFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set myDestFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("root").Folders("archiv")
    Set mySearchFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("root").Folders("alert-check")

    For Each MailItem In mySearchFolder.Items
        Set olItem = MailItem
        sText = olItem.Body

        If (InStr(1, sText, "no rows selected", vbTextCompare) > 0) Or (InStr(1, sText, "Es wurden keine Zeilen ausgewählt", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            olItem.Move myDestFolder
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I expect all emails will move to the archive folder in one go.

Comment: I don't think the `Or` is the reason your code doesn't move all email items. Looks to me as if the code stops executing prematurely. Do you show the complete code? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: You need to loop backwards when deleting items from a collection: `Dim n As Long: For n = mySearchFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1: Set olItem = mySearchFolder.Items(n): '... : Next n`. See the remarks section of [MailItem.Delete method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.delete).

Comment: @VBasic2008 Is that true also for a `For Each`-loop?

Comment: @FunThomas: thank you for your comment. It is the complete code.  I am Newbie to VBA and my debug didn't help me.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you for your comment. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would use, for next loop, which safely move items without affecting the remaining items.

```
Dim i as long
For i = mySearchFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set olItem = mySearchFolder.Items(i)
    sText = olItem.Body
    
    If InStr(1, sText, "no rows selected", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
       InStr(1, sText, "Es wurden keine Zeilen ausgewählt", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        olItem.Move myDestFolder
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you, @vbakim, your solution works.

Comment: I have a further question. I have to run the piece of code in the "MS Visual Basic for Applications" window. It works. But I like to run the script by clicking "Developer -> Macros -> Search_Move_Email" for convenience, it doesn't happen anything. What should I add in my code?

Comment: I woudl check the Macro setting. Select "Notification for all macros" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use `For Each` loops - you are modifying the collection as you are iterating over its elements, which will cause your code to skip some items.

Secondly, do not iterate over **all** items in a folder, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`. You can specify multiple conditions in your search query.

Thirdly (@vbakim), cache the `Items` collection before entering the loop: calling `Folder.Items` on each step of the loop would cause a brand new `Items` object to be retrieved every time.

```vb
dim restrictedItems
set restrictedItems = mySearchFolder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=(""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1000001F"" LIKE '%no rows selected%') OR (""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1000001F"" LIKE '%Es wurden keine Zeilen ausgewählt%') ")
for i = restrictedItems.Count To 1 Step -1
  Set olItem = mySearchFolder.Items(i)
  olItem.Move myDestFolder
next
```